NLua calling non existant function
I am currently adding lua support to my game written in c# using lua. Before calling a function in lua that can be there but doesn't have to be, it will check if the function exists in the script before it calls it. For example when an animation loops it will call "{CurrentAnimation}_Loop" for handling random stuff that changes before the loop, but not every animation needs to do stuff before the loop, but after checking if its null it still will try and call it which causes an exception to be thrown.
if (state.Looping)
{
    curAnimFrame = state.LoopPos;
    LuaFunction func = luaCode.GetFunction(curState + "_Loop");
    if(func != null)
        func.Call();
}

This is the code used for looping. When said function exists it works completely fine as expected, but when it doesn't it will throw NLua.Exceptions.LuaScriptException: 'attempt to call a nil value'. Obviously I could just make a function for every animation but that feels way too tedious and I don't want it calling empty functions. Anyone got any ideas on what I can do?
EDIT:
Comment by Wh1t3rabbit basically fixed it. Now I just have a function that will check if the object exists instead of getting the function from the lua state itself.
public void CallLuaFunc(string function, params object[] args)
{
    LuaFunction func = luaCode[function] as LuaFunction;
    if (func != null)
        func.Call(args);
}


Have a look at func in the debugger in both cases - exists and doesn’t exist - and see what’s different: there might be something you can use. ref

This bug report mentions GetFunction always returning a LuaFunction even if the function is not actually defined in Lua. The workaround seems to be using indexing instead of GetFunction func = luaCode[curState + "_Loop"] instead of func = luaCode.GetFunction(curState + "_Loop")
